# Maven doxygen plugin

Tags: java, maven, doxygen

Does anyone know if there is any Maven plugin for generating documentation using doxygen?

I've tried to use this one from [DoodleProject](http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/mavenite/doxygen-maven-plugin/index.html) but it doesn't seem to exist anymore because I can't access the repo. In addition, this one from [SoftwareEntwicklung Beratung Schulung](http://mvn.supose.org/projects/mavendoxygen/wiki) doesn't seem to have any documentation on how to use it.

Comment: If you can wait one day or two i can regenerate the docs and put it back online. It seemed that i accidently removed the docs.

Comment: So current state is available http://khmarbaise.github.io/doxygen-maven-plugin/. Currently it is not working with Maven 3.1 (i will check that).

Comment: @khmarbaise The docs seem to be missing still/again

Comment: The docs are online. Checked a minute before.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a plugin I liked, so I wrote my own.

It's available through maven central, and the homepage is at http://www.pcl-solutions.com/maven/doxygen-maven-report/1.0/.

Please feel free to join the users list and send me feedback (leaving it here is probably abusing SO)

Comment: the link no longer appears valid. redirects to a login page.